# what is Null Test in java? and how to rewrite the code to do the same by avoiding null test

Tags: java

I would like to know what is null test in java? How to rewrite the below code by  avoiding null test. I was asked this question in an online test. I'll be grateful for any help offered.

```
String mystere() throws IOException {
      InputStream input = null;
      try {
        input = new InputStream(new File("foo.txt"));
        return new Scanner(input).nextLine();
      } finally {
        if (input != null)
          input.close();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `null` test is the `input != null` condition here.

In your code if the constructor of the stream throws an exception the reference remains `null` so there is no way to call `close` on it, therefore the constructor call could be before the `try-catch` block. The generic pattern is the following:

```
    final InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("foo.txt"));
    try {
        // do something with the stream
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
```

Please note that I've changed `new InputStream(...)` to `new FileInputStream(...)`. `InputStream` an interface, you cannot instantiate it.

In Java 7 it's a little bit simpler:

```
try (final InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("foo.txt"))) {
    // do something with the stream
}
```

References: *Guideline 1-2: Release resources in all cases* in the [Secure Coding Guidelines for the Java Programming Language, Version 4.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html) documentation.